# Cant pass the argument for a constructor from a switch case statement

Tags: c++, constructor

I tried this:

```
class Quota{
    private:
        ....
    public:
        Quota(const int sizee): ID(sizee), percentage(sizee){
            quotaa = 100;
        }
        ....
};
int main(){
    int intake, choice;
    cin >> choice;
    Quota q;
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
        cin >> intake;
        q(intake);
        break;
        case 2:
        ...
        default:
    }
    q.xyz();
}
```

How can i make this work? i need to initialize an object of the `Quota` class and pass the argument for the constructor in the `switch` statement while still being able to access the same object anywhere else in the main function?

Comment: Can you `Quota q;` `q(intake);`? Even if you don't use switch?

Comment: You can't construct an object after it has already been constructed. What's wrong with `q = Quota(intake);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the line that constructs the object after the `switch` statement.

```
int intake, choice;
cin >> choice;
switch(choice){

    case 1:
    cin >> intake;

    // Don't do this.
    // q(intake);
    break;

    case 2:
    ...

    default:
}

// Now that you have intake, construct q.
Quota q(intake);
```

Comment: Given little information about the surrounding code this is the best answer, but I don't think you want the `q(intake);` in case 1 of the switch.

Comment: @user4581301, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the `switch`: as it is, you wouldn't be able to write

```
Quota q; // default construct
q(intake);
```

The first statement `Quota q` constructs a `Quota`, and that's where you need to pass the `intake` parameter.

You can use the copy constructor to do

```
Quota q;
q = Quota(intake);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call constructors after the value is declared.

Try this instead:

```
q = Quota(intake);
```

You'll also need to declare a default constructor for `Quota` initializing all members to "reasonable defaults"